# How to Block Image Loading in GMAILS Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail, inboxsdk

In my simple gmail chrome extension - I want to prevent loading of image in a sent mail.

Inside  **`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`** is working when I include

```
urls: [ "*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" ]
```

in the urls array. But this will fire for all the images I only want to fire for this pattern       `"*://*/#https://mysite/*",`

But it is not firing at all - If I include **googleusercontent** url it is working with details.url in this format - 

`https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/IB4W2KvisZjL2rgC....#https://mysite/*`

**MANIFEST**

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.googleusercontent.com/*",
    "*://*/#https://track1/*",
    "*://*.googleusercontent.com/*/://track1/*"
],
```

and in the **background script**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) {
            console.log(details);    
        }, {
        urls: [
            "*://*/#https://track1/*",
        ]
       }, ['blocking']
 );
```

I think issue is with patter matching but I am not able to understand which is the right pattern to use

Comment: Hi Sandeep! Did you get the required pattern? or any other solution?

Comment: Yes @PallaviGoyal I finally found the issue . Let me explain below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) {
           // Here inside details.url - you see each image is in format https://googlecontent 
            console.log(details);    
        }, {
        urls: [
            "*://*/#https://track1/*",
        ]
       }, ['blocking']
 );
```

As mentioned above Inside details.url - you see each image is in format https://googlecontent 

So you need to include this pattern inside `urls` array.
Now how to grab required url link is

```
if (details.url.includes('<include link string here>') || details.url.includes('<other link here>')) {
    if (some condition to stop image load met) cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sandeep! I also found the same solution. Your answer confirms that I was on the right track, :-)

Comment: We used this solution but looks like that with latest chrome 72, all *googleusercontent/proxy* urls are not being caught in the background script listener. Did you see it happening too?